# shuffling the contents of Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor which which is composed of 2D arrays representing audio frames with shape 121*400. I want to shuffle the rows of individual arrays and not the arrays contained in the tensor. Is this possible without iterating through the tensor and shuffling each array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shuffle each array you could use this:

```
def tf_shuffle_second_axis(t):
    # Uniquely random along second axis
    rnd = tf.argsort(tf.random.uniform(t.shape),axis=1)
    # Add batch dimension for gathering
    rnd = tf.concat([tf.repeat(tf.range(t.shape[0])[...,tf.newaxis,tf.newaxis],tf.shape(rnd)[1],axis=1),rnd[...,tf.newaxis]],axis=2)
    # Return shuffled tensor
    return tf.gather_nd(t,rnd,batch_dims=0)
```

For example

```
a = tf.reshape(tf.range(16), [4,4])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]], dtype=int32)>
```

```
tf_shuffle_second_axis(a)
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 2,  1,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  5,  7],
       [ 9, 11, 10,  8],
       [14, 12, 13, 15]], dtype=int32)>
```

UPDATE

To shuffle the whole row use `tf.shuffle`

```
tf.random.shuffle(a)
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: You code shuffles the values randomly and not rows. I desire a situation where the whole row is shuffled e.g   row 1 now becomes row 3 and row 3 is shuffled to row 2.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, updated my answer